# JAVA GWT DialogBox how to add new line char

Tags: java, gwt

I am having an issue trying to add a new line to a DialogBox. I have tried the normal "\n" and also tried putting my lines inside of HTML style  tags. Neither of these attempts worked. Help is appreciated.

```
 DialogBox dialog = new DialogBox();
 dialog.setText(" Meter ID:\t\t" + blink.getMeterId() + "\n X coordinate:\t\t" + blink.getXCoord() + "\n Y coordinate:\t\t" + blink
                                .getYCoord());
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved via using setHTML to set the contents of the DialogBox

```
dialog.setHTML("<p> Meter ID: " + blink.getMeterId() + "</p> <p> X coordinate:\t\t" + blink.getXCoord() + "</p> <p> Y coordinate:\t\t" + blink
                                .getYCoord() + "</p>");
```

note this is using `<p></p>` for new paragraph but `<br>` and other html will work also

Answer (score 0):

just use another `\` as an escape character in a string:

new line: `\\n`

```
DialogBox dialog = new DialogBox();
 dialog.setText(" Meter ID:\\t\\t" + blink.getMeterId() + "\\n X coordinate:\\t\\t" + blink.getXCoord() + "\\n Y coordinate:\\t\\t" + blink
                                .getYCoord());
```